# jenssegers/laravel-mongodb $pipeline is not a list (unexpected index: "$group")

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, jenssegers-mongodb

I am getting this error when I try to use group and count.

ERROR:

> InvalidArgumentException in Aggregate.php line 93:
>   $pipeline is not a list (unexpected index: "$group")

MongoDB version: **3.2.9**

jenssegers/mongodb version : **3.1.0-alpha**

Here is my code.

```
$analytics = DB::collection('analytics')->raw( function ( $collection ) {
            return $collection->aggregate([
                '$group' => [
                    '_id'    => [ 'campaign_id' => '$campaign_id', 'type' => '$type' ],
                    'count'  => ['$sum' => 1],
                ]
            ]);
        });
```

I've also tried this code (enclosing aggregate in array) following solution form  [this issue](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/880)

```
$analytics = DB::collection('analytics')->raw( function ( $collection ) {
            return $collection->aggregate([
                [
                    '$group' => [
                        '_id'    => [ 'campaign_id' => '$campaign_id', 'type' => '$type' ],
                        'count'  => ['$sum' => 1],
                    ]
                ],
            ]);
        });
```

but this time error is

> UnexpectedValueException in compiled.php line 16079:
>   The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this in the end? Thx!

Comment: @mils that was A long time ago. I did not exactly remember how exactly I solved the issue. Most probably that was due to incorrect syntax...